# ReactJS facebook loginget Authorization Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

I'm trying to get facebook Authorization Code in my reactjs web App using  [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login) but it will always return access token and user details.I tried different paramters but isn't work .Can someone help me to identify my problem

```js
<FacebookLogin
                  appId="My app ID"
                  responseType="code"
                  callback={this.facebookLoginSuccess}
                  render={renderProps => (
                    <Button
                      onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                      className="btn-social facebook"
                    >
                      <i className="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" />
                    </Button>
                  )}
                />
```

my output is something like

```
{name: "Sam Mate", id: "14295543169074320", accessToken: "EAAdfZBwOiVPUBABjYIj1KLOKEPyQHAA5iItKtOoHYUrTLydZB…9dAJosMJaY5K6HJq7QaOXFmnfBvHXsIkG6WOgKFmtM1AzHAZD", userID: "10425498127074330", expiresIn: 6531, …}
```

Comment: That’s how things are supposed to work with the client-side login flow. If you want to get a code first to exchange for a token via a server-side API call, then you need to implement the server-side login flow, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow (Don’t ask me how to do that using your framework though.)

Comment: Thanks @misorude .I'll look into that. I have already implemented server side logic and it works perfectly with google auth. only problem I coudn't get facebook Authorization Code. Thanks again.